# leetcode Binary Tree Preorder Traversal WA: Input:{1} Output:1 Expected:[1]

Tags: c++

I surely return a vector ,but the judging system seems to ignore it and puts  my output without "[]".

Could any one help me?

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Definition for binary tree

  struct TreeNode {

     int val;
     TreeNode *left;
     TreeNode *right;
     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
  };
 */

class Solution {

public:

    vector<int> preorderTraversal(TreeNode *root) {

    stack<TreeNode*> s;
    vector<int> ans;
    if(!root) 
        return ans;

    while(root || !s.empty())
    {
        if(root)
        {
            cout<<root->val<<endl;
            ans.push_back(root->val);
            s.push(root);
            root = root->left;          
        }
        else
        {
            root = s.top();
            s.pop();
            root = root->right;
        }
    }
    return ans;


    }
};
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are asking for.

Comment: Sorry about that. This was the problem I tried to solve on leetcode: https://oj.leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-preorder-traversal/ .My problem is that I returned a vector <int> in my code, but the judging system told that the return value was a number instead of a vector<int>.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake..

It seemed that the judging system took the value from `cout<<root->val<<endl;` as the return value , which led to my problem. Simply deletling the line could solve my problem.

Thanks everyone viewing and caring for this issue!